# bounds of Lyapunov operator

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, control-theory, positive-semidefinite, lyapunov-functions

Let $A$ be a nonsingular matrix of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,
and let $ L_AP=A^TPA$.
Let $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $L_AP\geqslant \beta P$ holds for all $P>0$. Let $\lambda_i,\sigma_i$ are the $i$-th eienvalue and sigular value of $A$, respectively.
I have two problems in the following:

**Prob 1:**
Suppose the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ is $1,\forall~i$.
I wonder if the upper bound of $\beta$ is $\min_i|\lambda_i|^2$.

**Prob 2:**
Suppose $A$ has have eienvalue whose algebraic multiplicity is more than $1$.
I wonder if there is a upper bound of $\beta$. If there is, is it $\min_i\sigma_i^2$?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In all cases, $\min_i |\lambda_i|^2$ is an upper bound to $\beta$ (regardless of the multiplicity of the eigenvalues of $A$).

First, Suppose that $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$ and that $v \in \Bbb R^n$ is an associated eigenvector. For $t \in \Bbb R$, let $P_t = vv^T + tI$. Note that $P_t > 0$ for all $t > 0$. We note that
$$
L_A(P_t) - \beta P_t = A^Tvv^TA - \beta vv^T + t(A^TA - \beta I)
\\ = (\lambda^2 - \beta) vv^T + t(A^TA - \beta I).
$$
This matrix must be positive semidefinite for all $t > 0$. Because the limit of positive semidefinite matrices is positive semidefinite, taking the limit of the above as $t \to 0^+$ allows us to conclude that $(\lambda^2 - \beta)vv^T$ is positive semidefinite, which can only occur if $\beta \leq \lambda^2$.

Now, suppose that $\lambda = a + bi$ with $b \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$, and that $v = x + iy$ (with $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$) is an associated eigenvector. Note that
$$
A^T(x + iy) = (a + bi)(x + iy) = (ax - by) + i(bx + ay) \implies\\
A^Tx = ax - by, \quad A^Ty = bx + ay.
$$
Using this fact, verify that
$$
L_A(xx^T + yy^T) = (a^2 + b^2)(xx^T + yy^T) = |\lambda|^2 (xx^T + yy^T).
$$
With that established: for $t > 0$, let $P_t = xx^T + yy^T + tI$. We find that
$$
L_A(P_t) - \beta P_t = (|\lambda|^2 - \beta)(xx^T + yy^T) + t(A^TA - \beta I).
$$
This matrix must be positive semidefinite for all $t > 0$. Because the limit of positive semidefinite matrices is positive semidefinite, taking the limit of the above as $t \to 0^+$ allows us to conclude that $(\lambda^2 - \beta)vv^T$ is positive semidefinite, which can only occur if $\beta \leq |\lambda|^2$.

Thus, we conclude that $\beta \leq |\lambda_i|^2$ for all $i$, which means that $\min_i |\lambda_i|^2$ is indeed an upper bound for $\beta$.

Comment: Your proof is very inspiring. But seems that in your derivation $A^Tv=\lambda v$ must be satisfied. What if the condition that $A^Tv=\lambda v$ is not satisfied, or there is Jordan block? For example, suppose that $E^{-1}A^TE=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$, where $E=[e_1, e_2]$. In this case, we have $A^Te_2=e_1+e_2$, and condition that $A^Tv=\lambda v$ is not satisfied.

Comment: @Lostbird In that case you can simply take $v=e_1$. An eigenvalue will always have at least one associated eigenvector.

Comment: What if I take $Pt=e_2e_2^T+tI$? Since $P$ has to be generic, it is OK if we just let $Pt=e_1e_1^T+tI$? And one more question, why you choose $P=vv^T+tP$? I think here we have to let $v$ to take all possible eigenvectors of $A$ since we would like $P$ to be general.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "$P$ has to be generic/general". If the statement $L_AP \geq \beta P$ applies for **all** positive definite matrices $P$, then it must apply when $P = P_t$. Using that, I deduced an upper bound for $\beta$.

Comment: Let $E^{-1}A^TE=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$, where $E=[e_1,e_2]$. Clearly $A^Te_2=e_1+e_2,\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$. If we let $P=e_2e_2^T+I$, is the bound for $\beta$ still be $1$?

Comment: It seems that you are struggling with the logic of the proof, maybe this analogy will help. Suppose we are given that there is a constant $\beta$ such that for all $x > 2$, $x^2 \geq \beta$. We know that $x = 3$ is an example of a number that satisfies $x > 2$. Thus, we can deduce (by looking at only one value of $x$) that $3^2 \geq \beta \implies \beta \leq 9$. This is not necessarily the best possible upper bound, but every $x > 2$ gives us an upper bound. Likewise, for your problem, every $P > 0$ gives an upper bound, and some of these bounds are better than others.

Comment: Another way to put things: the inequality involving $\beta$ can be expressed as $f_A(P) \geq \beta$ (for all $P > 0$), where
$$
f_{A}(P) = \lambda_{\min}(P^{-1}L_A(P)).
$$
It follows that for every $P > 0$, $\beta \leq f_A(P)$. If we wanted the **best** possible upper bound for $\beta$, we could say that
$$
\beta \leq \inf_{P > 0} f_A(P).
$$

Comment: I am not sure if I get your point, @Ben Grossmann. So here are my points and what I would like to do.

I would like get the **best** possible upper bound for $\beta$, or expressed in your way, I would like to get 

$$
\beta_0\triangleq\inf_{P>0}f_A(P)
$$


After your last comment, I looked up some papers, and
found some hints in this paper
[CONDITIONING OF THE STABLE, DISCRETE-TIME LYAPUNOV
OPERATOR]('https://iri.columbia.edu/~tippett/pubs/tippett_simax.pdf').

Comment: In this paper, I found in Theorem 3.1 that 
$$
1-\sigma_1^2(A)\leq\|\mathcal{L}_A\|_p\leq 1+\sigma_1^2(A)
$$
where $\sigma_1(A)$ is the largest singular value of $A$, $\mathcal{L}_AP=P-APA^T$, and $\|\cdot\|_p$ is the Schatten $p$-norm defined as 
$$
\|S\|_p=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (\sigma_i(S))^p \right)^{1/p}
$$

So here is what I want to do:
I guess $\beta_0$ can be expressed as $\lambda_i(A),\sigma_n(A) ,A$, where $\sigma_n(A)$ is the smallest singular value of $A$, or maybe just $\beta_0=\sigma_n^2(A)$. Your proof is inspiring, yet so far is not associated with $\sigma_i(A)$.

Comment: The url of the paper is: https://iri.columbia.edu/~tippett/pubs/tippett_simax.pdf